# Ember Select set default value when the content change

Tags: ember.js

I have got 2 selects, and the second one (multiple) depends on the first one (simple)

First one:

```
{{view Ember.Select content=siteGroups selection=selectedSiteGroup}}
```

Second one:

```
 {{view Ember.Select content=sites optionLabelPath="content.name"  value=selectedSite multiple=true selection=selectedSiteDefault}}
```

So, the selectedSiteGoup (select 2) changes the content of the first one.

I have set the default value of the second one:

```
selectedSiteDefault: function(){
  return this.get('sites.firstObject');
}.property('selectedSiteGroup')
```

And it works, but when the content change (due to the first select) it doesnt set any value as default.

How could I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hawig/2/edit) with 2 select boxes. The contents of the second select box is based on the first select box.

The default value of the second select box is the last item.

```
var continents = ['America', 'Europe', 'Asia'];
var countries = {
  'America': ['Texas','New York'],
  'Europe': ['Estonia','Germany'],
  'Asia': ['India','China']
};

App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {
      'continents': continents,
      'countries': countries
    };
  }
});

App.IndexController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  continent: 'Asia',
  country: function() {
    return this.get('countries.'+this.get('continent'));
  }.property('continent'),
  countrySel: function() {
    return this.get('country.lastObject');
  }.property('country.[]')
});

{{view Ember.Select content=content.continents valueBinding="continent"}}
{{view Ember.Select content=country selection=countrySel}}
```

Comment: Thanks! but then how do you store the value selected in the second select? value=?